# do_shortcode is not working on my index.php

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I register a shortcode on my functions.php

```
function offer_intro_shortcode ($atts, $content=null) {

    $offer = shortcode_atts( array (
        'title' => '',
        'text' => '',
    ), $atts );

    extract ($offer);
    return '<div class="center gap">
            <h3>'.$title.'</h3>
            <p class="lead">'.$text.'</p>
            </div>';
}
add_shortcode ('offer', 'offer_intro_shortcode');
```

Then i write on wordpress post:

```
[offer title='What We Offer' text='Look at some of the recent projects we have completed for our valuble clients']
```

Then i query for this shortcode on my index.php like do_shortcode('[offer]')

But it is not working

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "not working" please? (As an aside: "valuble clients" should be "valu**a**ble clients").

Comment: that is spelling mistake. i query for the shortcode by writing do_shortcode('[offer]').. but it is not displaying the content what i write in my post, [offer title='What We Offer' text='Look at some of the recent projects we have completed for our valuable clients']

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
echo do_shortcode("[offer title='What We Offer' text='Look at some of the recent projects we have completed for our valuble clients']");
```

check this is working or not.

Comment: It is working but i want control it from my wordpress directory

Comment: you want to write add_shortcode ('offer', 'offer_intro_shortcode'); into your index.php file right?

Comment: i write [offer title='What We Offer' text='Look at some of the recent projects we have completed for our valuble clients'] on a wordpress post. and i want to query that by do_shortcode('[offer]') where i want to display that. When i did that, index.php get the style but not the content

Comment: hey, i am confuse please clarify what you want to display.

Comment: the title and the text what i write on wordpress post

Comment: that i already give a answer write directly that line in index.php file instead of "[offer]". if you don't pass any argument in "[offer]" then it dosen't display anything.

Comment: if i write do_shortcode('[offer]'), i think, it should automatically get from my post. why i have to write on my index page [offer title='What We Offer' text='Look at some of the recent projects we have completed for our valuble clients']? is that really dynamic?

Comment: then you need to define a default value into your offer_intro_shortcode function. currently you are passing a '' so for that it's not displayed anything right.

Answer (score 0):

After $atts add another parameter i.e shortcode so it would become.

```
 $offer = shortcode_atts( array (
        'title' => '',
        'text' => '',
    ), $atts,'offer' );
```